# Is the Embedded MongoDB Database of Spring in Memory Only?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Of course, a fresh install with Spring Boot that includes MongoDB leads lead to an embedded version of MongoDB.  I know that the standard way of doing this adds something like the following to either a Maven or Gradle setup:

`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive`

While I have MongoDB already setup on my own computer for other testing purposes, would I be right that MongoDB stays in memory only?

Thank you.

Comment: For the normal case, using common DB in server to dev is good for many things. For you, you need and MongoDb and already had 1 in your local computer. So the build-in mongo in spring is a little useless. And the stage of the embedded mongo db is what you want to know?

Comment: I am wondering if Spring will allow the same things for a local database as it allows for an embedded database.  I hope that there is a dependency from Spring that connects to a local database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing ...

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive
```

with ...

```
org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:2.1.8.RELEASE
```

... seems to fix the issue.

This points Spring to a locally installed database instead of creating an embedded database.  This would go in a *pom.xml* file for **Maven** or a *build.gradle* file for **Gradle**.